# Only Execute setInterval function in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
var intervalHandle ;
var currentOpacity=0;

function beginAnimate() {
    current_question_div = document.getElementById(current_question);
    intervalHandle = setInterval(function(){
        animateBox(current_question_div)
    }, 200);
    alert("Hellow ashik !");
}

function animateBox(current_question_div) {
    current_question_div.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue"; 
    currentOpacity = currentOpacity + .091; 
    current_question_div.style.opacity = currentOpacity; 
    if(currentOpacity > 1) {     
        alert("END");
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
    }
}
```

```
<P onclick="beginAnimate">Click</p>
```

Everything is ok, but `alert("Hellow ashik !");` working while interval is in execution. I want to open the `alert("Hellow ashik !")` When the `clearInterval` occurred. Means now other JavaScript code is executing in parallel while interval is also executing. I need to execute only one thread at a time. Please help. Is there a way to execute this code one by one. Thanks.

Comment: There is no other thread, JS does not execute in parallel. The interval will run *asynchronously*.

Comment: The code is executing "one by one". When you call *setInterval*, the passed function will not be called for at least another 200ms whereas the next line of code (`alert('...')`) will be called immediately. There is only one thread working, javascript is single threaded, so the function passed to *setInterval* can't run until *beginAnimate* has finished (even if you set an interval of 0).

Answer (score 0):

This code *should* accomplish what you want:

```
var intervalHandle,
    currentOpacity = 0;

function beginAnimate() 
{
    current_question_div=document.getElementById(current_question);

    /* call any other functions that need to run before the animation starts here */
    alert("Hellow ashik !");

    intervalHandle = setInterval(function(){ 
        // note 'endAnimate()' is passed to the 'animateBox()' function as a callback
        animateBox(current_question_div, endAnimate)
    }, 200);

    /* call any functions that can run while the animation is running here */
}

function endAnimate() {
    alert("The end!");
    /* call any other functions that need to be run after the animation here */
}

function animateBox(current_question_div, callback) {
    current_question_div.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    currentOpacity = currentOpacity + .091;
    current_question_div.style.opacity = currentOpacity;

    if(currentOpacity>1)
    {     
        alert("END");
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        if (callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') {
            callback();
        }
    }
}

<P onclick="beginAnimate">Click</p>
```

JavaScript is a single threaded language -- ignoring WebWorkers or other workarounds. However, it is asynchronous and because of that you often see behavior that looks like threading. One way to work around these issues is to use the [**callback pattern**](http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript).

In the callback pattern, you pass a function to be called later when your asynchronous function completes. JavaScript makes this simple as functions are first class objects and can be passed or assigned to just as easily as a number.

Comment: Thanks. But actually i want to execute the alert in beginanimate. I mention only the alert. But there may be so many task, function calling in begin animate after alert("Hellow ashik !");

Comment: Sure, that doesn't actually change the code much though. You still need to use the observer, or one of the other async, patterns.

Comment: And if I am putting the alert in beginanimate it is executing before the interval is end. Thanks. @klyd

Comment: You might try playing with the code a bit. The above essentially represents `before`, `during`, and `after` states of the animation. You should be able to get any order of operations you want out of that. Otherwise please clarify what you're looking for. Your comments and op seem contradictory.

Comment: Still the beginAnimate code and interval is in parallel execution. Thanks. Is there another way?

Comment: I want to execute the whole interval task then want to execute anyother javascript . But interval is executing parallely.

Comment: I tried with your code. But the output is same. thanks.

Comment: The interval is *not* running in parallel. JavaScript is *not* multithreaded. What's happening is [**`setInterval`**](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) schedules an event that's fired in the future. When the event fires, the event's callback is run. This is the nature of JavaScript. You will need to work around that nature using one of the supplied patterns. You **cannot** pause execution in JavaScript because there is no additional thread to pause.

Comment: I suspect you have a lot of code that you want to run after the animation that you did not include. There is no way to pause other portions of the script. ***All*** code that must be run after the animation must be called from the `endAnimate` function. All code called before the interval will most likely be completed before the first interval event is even fired.

Answer (score 0):

In a browser, javaScript has a single-threaded nature, thus it executes on a single thread per window. This means that the execution diagram is one dimensional: javaScript can only ever execute one piece of code at a time.

The browsers are event-driven. Most events are asynchronous, such as mouse clicks, key press, and `timers`. They are only run when there is an opening in the execution; and in the meantime, they are forced to get into the event queue waiting for execution.

```
<p id="test"></p>

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "a";

var intervalHandle = setInterval(function(){
    callback();
}, 200);

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "c";

function callback() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "b";  
    //here where should be located all the code supposed to be executed after the timeinterval.
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
    //here where should be located all the code supposed to be executed after the clearInterval.
}
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/dbjkkvxz/2/) to see the working example.

In the example above, the javascript thread starts setting the content of p to "a", then delays the execution of callback. This goes to the Event queue on the nearest timer tick after 200ms. And then continue execution, setting the content of p to "c".

So if you want to execute something after the clearInterval, then you should place it after the clearInterval.

Hope it's useful!